# why I get the error: Undefined function or variable 'shapes'

Tags: matlab, function, variables

I'm working in matlab 2016.
I have a program code. It needs to work correctly.
Here is the program:

```
    clear all;    
addpath('..');    
training_files = dir('cootes/*.bmp.mat');    
for i=1:numel(training_files)
    load(sprintf('cootes/%s', training_files(i).name));     
    app = imread(sprintf('cootes/%s', training_files(i).name(1:end-4)));

    % Map RGB colors to [0,1]
    appearances(:,:,:,i) = double(app) ./ 255;      
    shapes(:,:,i) = xy2ij(annotations, size(app,1));
end     
load('cootes/triangulation.mat');    
test_img = 2;
one_out = [1:test_img-1, test_img+1:size(shapes,3)];    
AAM = build_model_2d(shapes(:,:,one_out), appearances(:,:,:,one_out), 'triangulation', triangulation);    
fprintf('\n******************************************************* 2D FITTING *******************************************************\n\n');
disp 'Figure 1: leave-one-out fitting result (red mesh) using as intialization a random shape from the training set (blue mesh).'
disp 'Figure 2: reconstructed appearance.'
disp 'Usage: Hit a random key to use a different initialization shape. Use CTRL+C to quit.'
fprintf('\n');    
while 1
    init_shape = one_out(round(rand()*(numel(one_out) - 1) + 1));
    try
        [ fitted_shape fitted_app ] = fit_2d(AAM, shapes(:,:,init_shape) + repmat([-5 -5], [size(shapes, 1) 1 1]), appearances(:,:,:,test_img), 20);

        figure(1)
        imshow(appearances(:,:,:,test_img));
        hold on;
        triplot(AAM.shape_mesh, shapes(:,2,init_shape), shapes(:,1,init_shape), 'b');
        triplot(AAM.shape_mesh, fitted_shape(:,2), fitted_shape(:,1), 'r');
        hold off;           
        figure(2)
        imshow(fitted_app);             
        pause;
    catch ME
        fprintf('Fitting diverged: %s\n', ME.message);
    end
end
```

After starting the program appears the following error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'shapes'.

Error in annotate_test (line 29)
AAM = build_model_2d(shapes, appearances, 'triangulation', triangulation);
```

Сan anyone explain why the variable 'shapes' is not defined. Although clearly spelled out:

```
shapes(:,:,i) = xy2ij(annotations, size(app,1));
```

Please help, I'm newby and don't understand where can be the error.

Comment: The variable `training_files` must be empty causing the first `for` loop to not execute. This means that it cannot find the files you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`training_files = dir('cootes/*.bmp.mat'); %error is here`

try this.

```
training_files = dir(fullfile(mypath,'*.bmp.mat')); % should work if you have .bmp.mat files in that path
```

Comment: Thank you, now a new problem has arisen. To use this method, it is necessary that the file name was not very long. But it turns out that I have used once all the necessary files, and they are recorded all in the name. The result is a very long name. Here is the error:                   <<Error using
dir
Pathname
'D:\progy\matlab;C:\Users\Петруха\Documents\MATLAB;C:\Users\Петруха\Downloads\icaam-1.0-r17\icaam; ......  '         is too long.

Error in
annotate_test
(line 10)
training_files
=
dir(fullfile(path,
'*.bmp.mat'));>>

Comment: Maybe there are still some ways?

Comment: Do not use `path`, it is [Matlab function](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html) that return your paths, thus it will be very long. Use `training_files = dir(fullfile(string_with_your_path,'*.bmp.mat'))`

Comment: say I understand you correctly, that it is necessary instead of <string_with_your_path> to prescribe the full path to the folder that contains the files <*.bmp.mat>?

Comment: The problem is that I registered the full path, and as a result matlab gives an error and closes

Comment: let say the path to your folder that contains 'bmp.mat' files is: mypath='C:\Users\yourname\Documents\Matlab\myfiles';                                 training_files = dir(fullfile(mypath,'*.bmp.mat'));                                                  %you can set a breakpoint and step over your code to see what is going on.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try.

Comment: I have tried to use breakpoints and determined that the problem lies in the 30 line. When building the model. The program just crashes.

Comment: Here is this line:   AAM = build_model_2d(shapes(:,:,one_out), appearances(:,:,:,one_out), 'triangulation', triangulation);